Building an Agent-Based Model Using MESA
I'm new to agent-based modeling with Python (Mesa). I want to build a model of a market where agents bid on products, and if a seller accepts a buyer's bid, a deal is made. My problem is how to assign different attributes to agents, such as the proposed price, buyer/seller status, etc. Any suggestions on how to approach this?
Best,
I’m just confused and don’t know from what should I start!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
